# Paypal payment window closes chrome extension popup in MacOS Catalina

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, paypal

I'm building a chrome extension in ReactJS and I've integrated `react-paypal-button-v2` button.
It works well on windows chrome browser but issues in **MacOS Catalina**, when we close the payment window popup, it also closes the extension popup. hence we can't detect payment callback functions like `onSuccess()` to determine success or failure.

Comment: I've got exactly the same problem and couldn't figure out why so far. Did you have any success?

Comment: No @Sandro_V, I moved to Windows.